# CLLocationManager tracks wrong Location (Track Me)

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am implementing `Track me` option in my code.`CLLocationManager` is not working as expected.when I start app remain at the same position ,`CLLocationManager` changes around 20-30 meters with-in 1 min minutes..then I remain Constant.

And If i change my position to track same thing happen in starting 1 min `CLLocationManager` moves 20-30 min extra then moves with my speed..

Why this happening..

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

  self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.0001;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 }


-(void)start {


[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];    
}


 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation 
       fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation {

[self processLocationChange:newLocation fromLocation:oldLocation];

 }


 -(void)processLocationChange:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:oldLocation {

if (newLocation != oldLocation) {

    NSLog(@"Moved from %@ to %@", oldLocation, newLocation);

    CLLocation* lastKnownLocation = NULL;
    if ([self.locationPoints count] > 0) {
        lastKnownLocation = [self.locationPoints objectAtIndex:[self.locationPoints count] - 1];
    }
    else {
        lastKnownLocation = newLocation;
        self.bottomLeft = newLocation.coordinate;
        self.topRight = newLocation.coordinate;
    }

    // Check for new boundaries
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = newLocation.coordinate;
    if (coords.latitude < bottomLeft.latitude || coords.longitude < bottomLeft.longitude) {
        self.bottomLeft = coords;
        NSLog(@"Changed bottom left corner");
    }
    if (coords.latitude > topRight.latitude || coords.longitude > topRight.longitude) {
        self.topRight = coords;
        NSLog(@"Changed top right corner");
    }




    double speed = fabs(newLocation.speed);
    double deltaDist = fabs([newLocation distanceFromLocation:lastKnownLocation]);
    double newAvgSpeed = (self.totalDistance + deltaDist) / ((double)[self getElapsedTimeInMilliseconds] / 1000.0);
    double accuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
    double alt = newLocation.altitude;

    NSLog(@"Change in position: %f", deltaDist);
    NSLog(@"Accuracy: %f", accuracy);
    NSLog(@"Speed: %f", speed);
    NSLog(@"Avg speed: %f", newAvgSpeed);




        self.totalDistance += deltaDist;
        self.currentSpeed = speed;
        self.avgSpeed = newAvgSpeed;
        self.altitude = alt;

        NSLog(@"Delta distance = %f", deltaDist);
        NSLog(@"New distance = %f", self.totalDistance);


        // Add new location to path
        [self.locationPoints addObject:newLocation];

        // Update stats display
        [self.first.start1 updateRunDisplay];

        // Update map view
        [self updateMap:lastKnownLocation newLocation:newLocation];

    }

}
```

Comment: Where you are calling the -(void)start Method.

Comment: ya its in the Viewcontroller..it works fine..there is no issue with that...problem is in the location..

Comment: Note: The method you are using `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation` is deprecated in iOS 6.

Comment: no I used iOs 5..iOs5 also gives me same changes

Comment: Ok. Try I suggested in my answer. Should solve your problem. Also I have edited title of question for better searchability.

Comment: Could you rewrite this sentences in more understandable language? I am not getting what you mean to say:
**"And If i change my position to track same thing happen in starting 1 min CLLocationManager moves 20-30 min extra then moves with my speed.."**

Comment: ya sorry ..means If i change My position to track the locations, it gives me extra added 20-30 meters

Comment: or any else changes required?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem in my current Pedometer app. I stretched, banged my head for couple of days. Then I found out that `CLLocationManager` is not able to track <5 meter distance and location generate updates. I kept `self.locationManager.distanceFilter =2.0;` and it gave me location updates even device was stationary. So I just changed distancefilter to 5.0 meter and it started working great. Try taking 5 meters it should work, I tested and all my wrong notifications issues vanished:

```
  self.locationManager.distanceFilter =5.0;
```

You are taking `self.locationManager.distancefilter=0.0001` which is I suppose out of capacity for `CLLocationManager` to track such a minor movement. Also you need to filter out old locations i.e. cached location updates as mentioned in **[Location Awareness Guide by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9)**. I have used this condition in my code to filter all events which are older than 5 seconds.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   CLLocation *currentLocation=[locations lastObject];
   NSDate* eventDate = currentLocation.timestamp;
   NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

   if(abs(howRecent)<5.0 && self.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy<=10 && self.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy>0)
   {
     //you have got fresh location event here.
   }
}
```

Comment: ya done the same but still changes the position from the constant position.

Comment: Strange then.. :/ Have you set `locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;`?

Comment: you can add me on skype patel.rohn

Answer (score 1):

I think give the distance filter effective with this

```
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
```

and you can start updating location method but also try this method these both methods are required to get exact location

```
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```